# Nginx: [warn] conflicting server name "non.com" on 0.0.0.0:80, ignored

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, nginx, vps

I have a node.js app running on my Ubuntu 14.04 VPS.
Everything is set up, from the dns through Cloudfare to running the app with pm2.

I am having problems with Nginx config files that are conflicting.
I am new to all this so I don't know how it works 100%.

Making some google searches showed me that by using the nano editor there might be `.save` files that make it conflict, I checked and that is not the case. Although, I do have the same file inside `/nginx/sites-available/` and `/nginx/sites-enabled/`.

here is the file called `default`:

```
server {
    listen 80;

    server_name domainName.com;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://MY-IP:3000/;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
}
```

Everytime I restart nginx I get a warning `nginx: [warn] conflicting server name "domainName.com" on 0.0.0.0:80, ignored`.

here is my `nginx.conf` file:

```
user www-data;
worker_processes 4;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

events {
        worker_connections 768;
        # multi_accept on;
}

http {

    ##
    # Basic Settings
    ##

    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    keepalive_timeout 65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;

    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    gzip on;
    gzip_disable "msie6";

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}
```

And the output of `ls -al /etc/nginx/sites-enabled`:

```
total 8
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Aug 28 07:33 .
drwxr-xr-x 5 root root 4096 Aug 28 07:33 ..
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   34 Aug 28 07:33 default -> /etc/nginx/sites-available/default
```

Output of `ls -alh /etc/nginx/conf.d/`:

```
total 8.0K
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4.0K Jul 12 06:35 .
drwxr-xr-x 5 root root 4.0K Aug 28 07:33 ..
```

I do not know what else to do, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Post your nginx.conf and `ls -al /etc/nginx/sites-enabled`

Comment: @TarunLalwani I added what you asked, it's at the end of the post.

Comment: Also need `ls -alh /etc/nginx/conf.d/` and content of any config inside it

Comment: can you move the /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default  to somewhere just for backup, and try to restart nginx without anyfiles there and post the output?

Comment: just did and now I get an error with the PID: `
`[error]: invalid PID number "" in "/var/run/nginx.pid"` @YamenNassif

Comment: just use service nginx start . instead of reload you've stopped it so you cant reload it

Comment: @YamenNassif when I run `service nginx status` it say it's not running and when I try running it it tells me `nginx: [error] invalid PID number "" in "/run/nginx.pid"
`

Comment: There you go @TarunLalwani

Comment: ok then re add the default one more time xD

Comment: Restart the server and try once again. The issue doesn't seem to be very obvious right now

Comment: @Mr-Swaggalicious please do as Tarun suggested i believe its something cached somewhere thats why i asked you to move the file away to make sure nothing is cached anymore, i guess this will work now.

Comment: Thank you @TarunLalwani and YamenNassif I was able to fix it. I will post the answer in a bit.

Answer (score 1):

To fix my issue I changed `proxy_pass http://MY-IP:3000/;` to `proxy_pass http://localhost:3000/;` on `/etc/nginx/sites-available/default`.

Then I stopped Apache2 using `sudo service apache2 stop`, restarted nginx with `sudo service nginx restart` and all worked perfectly fine.

Apparently I was using the IP of my VPS instead of using localhost as the address.

Comment: This helped me a lot! There was nothing wrong with my nginx config files and most of the answers on the web dealt with obvious problems there. My problem was, I had been invoking `certbot` with wrong options and it started up `apache` to try to authenticate and it was still running. Stopping it and restarting nginx fixed the problem (after updating certbot and running it with --nginx).

Answer (score 0):

Once you've confirmed that `domainName.com` isn't used in `server_name` anywhere else in your Nginx configs, look for `$hostname` or other Nginx variable, whose value might match your `server_name`:

[Alphabetical index of Nginx variables](http://nginx.org/en/docs/varindex.html)

**Example:**

```
server {
    server_name localhost $hostname;
    listen 80;

    access_log off;
}
```

Got me puzzled there for a while.